# Access 2007, Forms, I want to create a form that is comprised of 2 forms - one is a split, the other is regular

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to create a form that is comprised of 2 forms - one is a split, the other is regular.

I created the two forms separately.

```
Form 1 (regular): Salary information over the years

Salary 2007     Salary 2008...  Salary 2013

Form 2 (split form): Employee promotions and their dates

Date:    Title:    Event:    Salary:    Bonus:
```

I want to have them displayed on one form. One at the top and one at the bottom.

Please advise.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SQL, but specifically with Access 2007. Besides that, this question has (as it stands) nothing to do with programming. You need to create the forms "by hand" and then decide how to work with them. Check the answer I wrote below.

Comment: True - no sql but that's pretty much the only tag I can put at this rep. I will try your answer and see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the individual forms you need (let's call them `frmSalary` and `frmPromotions`, and then create a third form (let's call it `frmEmployeeInfo`) and add the two forms as subforms.

It should be something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
-   frmEmployeeInfo                                -
-                                                  -
-   -------------------------                      -
-   - frmSalary             -                      -
-   -------------------------                      -
-                                                  -
-   -------------------------                      -
-   - frmPromotions         -                      -
-   -------------------------                      -
----------------------------------------------------
```

Access lets you "link" the data in the subforms to data in the "parent" form. You can have general employee information in `frmEmployeeInfo` and you can link both `frmSalary` and `frmPromotions` to the parent form using the value of the `employeeId` field.

I suggest you to read a good book about Access... I've used a book called "Running MS Access", by John Viescas, but it is quite old (nevertheless it is useful... many characteristics in Access are the same now as they were in 1997 ;-) ).

A quick google query lead me to this page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx